# Parse string using javascript with N number of curly brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

I have below string which I want to parse

```
{field1=17/08/2017|field2=17/08/2017|field2=17/08/2017|field3=17/08/2017}
{field4 =Fijian|field5=English,Fijian}
```

Now here there two strings which is in curly brackets {} but there could be N number of strings as well, the delimiter between ending of first string and starting of next string could not be determined as sometime it could be separated with carriage return of sometime it could be in same line.

What I want is field wise value like `field1="17/08/2018"` and so on.

Could anyone please help me what is best way to parse this ?

Comment: you can split it using regex, but where are you getting this kind of message from. Better to go through the message construction logic before trying to parse it.

Comment: replace your { and } by | or get all string between {} then do a split on | for every sub array do a split on = you will get both value "fieldn" and <value> in new array. Try something then post your problem

Comment: if you have control over output response then go for JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
var strOne  = "{field1=17/08/2017|field2=17/08/2017|field2=17/08/2017|field3=17/08/2017}";
var strTwo = "{field4 =Fijian|field5=English,Fijian}";
   
strOne = strOne.replace("{","");
strOne = strOne.replace("}","");
var strArrayOne = strOne.split("|");
console.log(strArrayOne);

strTwo = strTwo.replace("{","");
strTwo = strTwo.replace("}","");
var strArrayTwo = strTwo.split("|");
console.log(strArrayTwo);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a **[regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)**, or **regex**. Specifically, I think you're looking for `/field(\d)+=(\w|,|\/)+/g`.

Breaking this down:

- `field` checks for the literal text `field`
- `(\d)+` checks for 1 or more digits
- `=` checks for the literal text `=`
- `(\w|,|\/)+` checks for one or more word character, comma, or forward slash
- The global flag `g` indicates that it should return all matches

You can check this by running `.match()` on the strings, and passing the regex as the parameter:

```js
var string = "{field1=17/08/2017|field2=17/08/2017|field2=17/08/2017|field3=17/08/2017}";
var string2 = "{field4=Fijian|field5=English,Fijian}";

var regex = /field(\d)+=(\w|,|\/)+/g;

console.log(string.match(regex));
console.log(string2.match(regex));
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

*Split* the string and *reduce* into the list of `field` key-value pairs - see demo below:

```js
var string = `{field1=17/08/2017|field2=17/08/2017|field2=17/08/2017|field3=17/08/2017} 
{field4 =Fijian|field5=English,Fijian}`;

var result = string.replace(/[\n\s]/g, '') // replace newline and space
  .split(/}{/) // split the string
  .reduce(function(p, c) {
    return p.concat(c.replace(/[{}]/g,'').split('|'));
  }, []);
  
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important;}
```

A simpler solution would be replace `}{` by `|` and then splitting - see demo below:

```js
var string = `{field1=17/08/2017|field2=17/08/2017|field2=17/08/2017|field3=17/08/2017} 
{field4 =Fijian|field5=English,Fijian}`;

var result = string.replace(/[\n\s]/g, '') // replace newline and space
  .replace(/}{/,'|').replace(/[{}]/g,'')
  .split('|');
  
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important;}
```